# How do I make the '@' symbol resolve to src

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

When I generate projects via CLIs, the @ symbol has already been configired to point to src, however I'm now building my own project from scratch and was wondering if someone could help me add this in myself.

I've tried adding the following to my webpack config, but no luck:

```js
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js'],
  alias: {
    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  }
},
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? How are you using the alias in your imports?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do this?

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'), //**Upd.** Replaced 'src' to './src'
    }
},
```

**Upd.**

If you have webpack config in another directory, then you should use relative path like this: `'../src'`.

Comment: sorry, there was a typo in the post, that's what I've been trying.

Comment: @James, I have updated my answer. Can you try to check it?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but the webpack config is at the same level as the src directory, so I don't think that applies.

Comment: @James, I have made another update. Can you check './src' instead of 'src'?

Comment: I figured out the problem, I needed to add the alias in .babelrc, as it was failing when I used jest, which doesn't actually use webpack.
{
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"],
      "alias": {
        "@": "./src"
      }
    }]
  ]
}